# Inserting links inside each iteration

Tags: express, pug

I'm new to jade and i've been trying to iterate over an array containing some text that needs to be turned into URL's. Anything I put in the parentheses after `list-group-item=` besides the array value will break the page. The only thing that works is putting the anchor tag in the next like. Is there no way to make the iteration into a link?

```
extend layout
block content
  .container
    .row
      .col-md-6.col-md-offset-3
        ul.list-group#servers
          - each server in servers
            li.list-group-item=( server.name) 
            a.small(href="server/"+server.id) List
```

Things I've tried:

```
li.list-group-item=( a.small(href="server/"+server.id) List )
```

I tried searching their docs but couldn't find any explanation or examples.

Answer (score 1):

Solved it

```
extend layout
block content
  .container
    .row
      .col-md-6.col-md-offset-3
        ul.list-group#servers
          - each i in servers
            li.list-group-item 
              a(href="server/"+i.id)
                =i.name
```

Moved the anchor to the next line and nested it under `li`. Nested the name underneath the anchor tag.